# Is it possible to remove shadow from VS Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I'm trying make as much as possible VS Code looking as the Sublime Material theme: https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme . I found only one bottle neck for now - is shadows.

They looking as an issue in the interface and took too much mine attention.

[image: Example of VS Code shadow]

All other stuff already are restyled using the `*.tmTheme` files and awesome `workbench.experimental.colorCustomizations`.

Would be glad for any proposals.

Comment: https://github.com/pirateminds/pirate-theme working sample can be found here. Shared my VS code config

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the time of writing this comment it is possible.

[`scrollbar.shadow`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_scroll-bar-control) allows to customize the color of all scroll-indicating shadows in the workbench.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "scrollbar.shadow": "#BADA55"
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Try it:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "scrollbar.shadow": "#ffffff00",
            "widget.shadow": "#ffffff00"
        },
```

Comment: This can be shortened to #0000

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you get to the right direction.

I was able to remove shadows by editing my workbench.main.css file located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\electron-browser\workbench.main.css`

I changed box-shadow to 0 px under the editable-preferences-editor-container

[CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odlVr.png)

[No shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g55aw.png)

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, copy and paste the code into your post.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in VSCode 1.11 without editing the editor's css

VSCode 1.12 is adding a number of new themeing the editor itself, using options such as

```
"scrollbarShadow": "#ff00ff00"
```

but this currently does not include the shadow color in split views like your example. Support for theming this is being tracked by https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25528